# Save + Publishing in Umbraco reverting back to previous save

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm using Umbraco 7.2.6 on my local machine using Visual Studio2013 (but haven't made any changes from there).

Occasionally (and only occasionally but has happened a few times) after Saving + Publishing (or sometimes just saving) and returning to my content editor later i find that the contents in the backend (i.e. content management area) have reverted to a previous save. The user side remains up to date however, but if i want to make any changes i need to fill out the content section again in the CMS.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: what if you use another browser to view the content? Can you see the correct content then? Maybe a caching problem of the browser?

Comment: I have been using only google chrome, i've just tried it in firefox and internet explorer and the same result. I also cleared the cache and nothing changed

Comment: its strange because you say that the front end is correct displayed, so the data must be correct saved into the database

Comment: do you see any errors in console while publishing, also do you see all versions in revision history?

Comment: Yes, it's quite strange, that the 2 parts are getting different data. i republished again and over the weekend the same thing has happened  i didn't check the console when publsihing, i will check next time i do,   @Chaitanya how can i check the revision history?

Comment: in content menu, "do something" and in "rollback", do you see the version changes? also in "audit trail" can you see save or publish actions done?

Comment: OK, the 'rollback' only seems to count to the last 5 publishes, which may have all been the same content.   
I can see a lot of action in audit trail, but it's a little annoying because i can't scroll down the list so i can only see as much as i can fit in my window.   are there reasons for these problems?

Comment: I don't know for sure, I have not experienced such problem. Generally content on frontend comes from cache in app_data/umbraco.config , you are saying frontend displays data correctly, so I wanted you to check if save and publish are being recorded or not. If not it may be possible that config file is getting updated but code for save/publish is breaking.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but it seems to happen when i close my VS solution. Looking at the rollback and audit and it seems to be missing my later saves. If the problem is to do with this, does that mean it's a problem with the config file?. and if so what could i do to fix it?